# Insert or ignore a record

Tags: sqlite

I have a table

```
CREATE TABLE "myTable" (
    "id" INTEGER NOT NULL, 
    "name" VARCHAR,
    PRIMARY KEY ("id")
)
```

and let's say it has 1 record

```
1 - James
```

I want to insert a new record. If it doesn't exist, insert it. If it does, do nothing.
I am not sure if the below query, is the right way to do this:

```
INSERT or IGNORE INTO myTable(id, name) VALUES(1, "Tom");
```

I tried it and I didn't get any error..

Comment: Which SQL server are you using?

Comment: I have tagged it: `SQLite`

Comment: Are you aware that OR IGNORE checks only UNIQUE or PRIMARY KEY constraints (here: only the `id`)?

Comment: No I didn't ! However, checking just the `id` is fine (fortunately). Thx for the info!

Comment: Would it really make sense to *ignore* a new record if it has the same ID but a different name? This is not what this feature is usually used for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your statement is fine for what you want to do.  However, you don't need to supply a value for `id` in SQLite.  You can just do:

```
INSERT INTO myTable(name)
    VALUES('Tom');
```

This will auto-increment the `id`, so you don't have to worry about duplicates.

Comment: I didn't know that auto-increment will occur, even if I haven't adde the `AUTOINCREMENT` when I created the table. Thx for the info!

Comment: @Nat95 . . . It is a wierdity of SQLite that integer primary keys are equivalent to an auto-increment column.  Don't get used to it in other databases!

Comment: @CL.  . . . There is no need to check if the record already exists if the OP let's the database assign the ids.

Answer (score 0):

You used INSERT IGNORE, and the row won't actually be inserted because it results in a duplicate key. Your id column is a PRIMARY KEY, and you already have the value 1 stored in the database.

The statement won't generate an error but it will generate a warning.